# Help identify Duplo Toolo brick

Tags: part-identification, duplo

I found a thick brick in my set, but couldn't find it on Bricklink by part number. It's look like an Intelligent Brick, but there are no extended pins.
Thanks!

[image: Top]

[image: Bottom]

[image: Part Number]

**UPDATE** [11.01.2020]:

Currently I have these Sound Key bricks:

```
● - pin
○ - no pin

41489  45752  45753
 ○ ○    ● ○    ○ ●
 ○ ○    ○ ●    ● ○
```

According to sound manual from [3590](https://thumbs.worthpoint.com/zoom/images4/1/0715/14/lego-duplo-explore-logic-drill_1_090077b6debe73136155b848adbfbee7.jpg) set, I missing last row of sounds (CHUCA..CHU. DRRILLL...DRIL.). After going through all the pin options, I found the right sound in this combination:

```
 ● ●
 ● ●
```

And it should be part number 45751, which is replaced by 41489 in my set.

Thanks all!

Comment: Do you happen to know which set this brick was included in?

Comment: @Alex I got this brick with other parts from [3590](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=44328) set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [*Part #41489c01 - Duplo Toolo Sloped Brick.*](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/41489c01)

[image]

In comments you wrote:

> "I also thought that its #45751c01, but the number on brick is 41489" – k1psead

Good question.  This is what [*LEGO.com*](https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/help/bricks-building/replacement-parts/identifying-lego-set-and-part-numbers-408100000009668) says about the molded numbers on individual pieces.

[image]

So, *LEGO* is saying the molded number is this piece's specific *Design Number* and that we can plug this number in on their Part Database and find the piece.

Let's try it...  Hmmm... Seems that answer is flawed.

So, how did I find it?  My initial search for "Duplo 41489", came with the search results below.

We both now know that there is a Star Wars set with this number, who's popularity has, unfortunately, skewed the wanted results for a *piece*. So, we can ignore anything Star Wars...

...Look at the third result with no reference to Star Wars.

[image]

The third result is pointing to *Peeron*, another LEGO Set Inventory Database, where the molded *Design Number* of this piece is set up correctly.

[image]

Let's double check by searching the number through ***[Peeron.com HERE](http://www.peeron.com/)***.

Comment: I also thought that its #45751c01, but the number on brick is 41489

Comment: The name suggests 45751c01 part have some electronics inside. However, the picture provided by OP doesn't seem to have any internals to produce sound.

Comment: I cross referenced "2949-1 - Remote Control Doze" through Bricklink and it switched this block from "41489c01" to "45751c01".  The Bricklink reference is wrong.  Relinked it to Peeron.com.

Comment: Following the recent update of the answer. Good catch with Peeron! However there's still some inconsistency. Peeron states this piece has been available in [2949](http://www.peeron.com/inv/sets/2949-1) set, however Bricklink has 45751c01 part in its [inventory](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=2949-1). Who's right then? It is either A). Incorrect inventory on Peeron or Bricklink, or B). This part is missing in BL catalog and needs to be added (and inventory for 2949 set updated, eventually).

Comment: Did a bit of research and it seems like Bricklink inventory is wrong. Bricklink is also missing 41489 part in its catalog. The reason behind such statement is simply instructions for [2949](http://bricks.rupprecht.me/?p=2353) set as well as [3589](https://e054fe06-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/kensphotopage/vintage/DSCF4970.JPG), where both sets should have same piece in their inventory. However you can clearly see 3589 has quite a few pictures explaining the use for intelligent brick, while 2949 has none. 2949 doesn't seem to have any way connecting intelligent brick to function.

Comment: @Alex None of these bricks has electronic parts inside. They differ in the pattern of pins.